# Why is this not causing an overflow error?

Tags: arrays, segmentation-fault, fortran

This is a simple program. I expected an error when `j>4`, but instead, Fortan shows that `array(2,5)=0.0`. It would be more useful if it gave me a stack overflow error.

What are your opinions?

```
program main 

implicit none

integer,parameter :: n=2,z=4
!real, dimension(1:2,1:4) :: array
real,allocatable ::  array(:,:)
integer :: i,j

allocate(array(n,z))
array = 0.0
array(1,1)=1.0 ; array(1,2)=2.0 ; array(1,3)=3.0 ; array(1,4)=4.0
array(2,1)=5.0 ; array(2,2)=6.0 ; array(2,3)=7.0 ; array(2,4)=8.0

do j=1,5
    do i=1,2
        write(*,*) i,j
    write(*,*) array(i,j)
    enddo
enddo

end program main
```

Comment: Just because you didn't allocate a specific space in memory doesn't mean it **will** crash if you try to use it. It may or may not cause problems depending on the situation. This is called Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is exceeding the bounds of the array.  That won't necessarily go past the boundary of the stack and is unlikely to do so with this small array.   Executables generated by Fortran compilers normally do not  check for illegal subscript errors. The reason is that such checking slows the program down.  You can request such checking with a compile-time option.  For example, with gfortran use `-fcheck=all` or `-fcheck=bounds`.  With ifort, `-check all` or `-check bounds`.  The "all" options include the "bounds" option and additional checks.

Comment: or even just `-check` with ifort

Answer (score 1):

Compiling with g95 -fbounds-check and running gives

At line 18 of file xoverflow.f90 (Unit 6)
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Fortran runtime error: Array element out of bounds: 5 in (1:4), dim=2

and gfortran -fbounds-check gives similar results. So you should test your code with these free compilers and at least the options -fbounds-check and -Wall .